# Ansible match host with key in json file

Tags: ansible

I've a playbook with a host group *my_hosts*

```
[my_hosts]
host1
host2
host3
```

I also have a json file, *data.json*, in the same directory as my playbook:

```
{
 "host1": "1.1.1.1",
 "host2": "1.1.1.2",
 "host3": "1.1.1.3"
}
```

I want a playbook to use the host file, and if the host matches the host key in the json file, print the IP. Ie when host=host1, '1.1.1.1' is printed.

The start of my playbook looks like this:

```
---
- name: Check IP
  hosts: my_hosts
  connection: local

  vars:
    version_file: "{{ lookup('file', 'data.json') | from_json }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Get IP
```

Is this possible in Ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try it?

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ version_file[inventory_hostname] }}"
```